# Oracle SQL Developer - Error message does not appear

Tags: sql, oracle

`CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION func_totalStaffOrders(
   v_staffID IN INTEGER)`
  `RETURN VARCHAR`
`AS
  v_totalOrders NUMBER;
  MESSAGE       VARCHAR2(100);`

`BEGIN
    IF v_staffID IS NOT NULL THEN
        SELECT COUNT(order_id)
        INTO v_totalOrders
        FROM orders
        WHERE staff_ID = v_staffID;`
    
        `MESSAGE := 'Staff with the ID ' || v_staffID ||' has took an overall of ' || 
        v_totalOrders || ' order/s.';
        RETURN MESSAGE;`
 
    `ELSE
        MESSAGE:='Null values are not allowed.';
        RETURN MESSAGE;
    END IF;
EXCEPTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  MESSAGE := 'Invalid staff ID entered.';
  RETURN MESSAGE;
WHEN OTHERS THEN
  MESSAGE := 'Error! ' || SQLERRM;`
  `RETURN MESSAGE;
END;`

This function counts the total number of orders made by a single staff member. It takes in a staff ID and returns the total number of orders. If I enter a staff ID that is not in the system, it does not show the exception message. Can anyone, help me please?

Answer (score 2):

Your query is always going to return a value.  If there are no matches, then the count will be 0, so `v_totalorders` will be zero.

No exception is generated.  You want explicit `if` logic on `v_totalorders`.